# Python: reduce precision pandas timestamp dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, dataframe

Hello I have the following dataframe

```
df = 

       Record_ID       Time
        94704   2014-03-10 07:19:19.647342
        94705   2014-03-10 07:21:44.479363
        94706   2014-03-10 07:21:45.479581
        94707   2014-03-10 07:21:54.481588
        94708   2014-03-10 07:21:55.481804
```

Is it possible to the have following?

```
df1 = 

       Record_ID       Time
        94704   2014-03-10 07:19:19
        94705   2014-03-10 07:21:44
        94706   2014-03-10 07:21:45
        94707   2014-03-10 07:21:54
        94708   2014-03-10 07:21:55
```

Comment: Is `Time` of type `datetime` ?

Comment: If I digit `type(df.Time[0])` it returns `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`

Comment: Also would be nice to understand why you need this. Could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need to compare different data frames at seconds level. For instance I have to do operations like  `df2 = df[df.time == df1.time]`

Comment: Could this be useful?
`df2 = df[(df.time - df1.time).abs() < pd.Timedelta('1 second')]`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could convert the underlying [`datetime64[ns]`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) values to `datetime64[s]` values using `astype`:

```
In [11]: df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('datetime64[s]')

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   Record_ID                Time
0      94704 2014-03-10 07:19:19
1      94705 2014-03-10 07:21:44
2      94706 2014-03-10 07:21:45
3      94707 2014-03-10 07:21:54
4      94708 2014-03-10 07:21:55
```

Note that since Pandas Series and DataFrames [store all datetime values as `datetime64[ns]`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7307) these `datetime64[s]` values are automatically converted back to `datetime64[ns]`, so the end result is still stored as `datetime64[ns]` values, but the call to `astype` causes the fractional part of the seconds to be removed.

If you wish to have a NumPy array of `datetime64[s]` values, you could use `df['Time'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')`.

Comment: Does pandas only support `datetime64[ns]`? Is there a built in way to change the precision. Say like only dates?

Comment: @mnky9800n: Currently, Pandas `NDFrames` only support `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Is there a plan to support other datetimes? I think there is obvious reasons since datetime64[ns] ranges can only be ~600 years long.

Comment: im getting `TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64[s]` now with padnas '0.25.3'

Comment: is there anything with less memory usage, like a datetime32?

Answer (score 20):

For pandas of version 0.24.0 or upward, you can simply set the freq parameter in ceil() function to get the precison you want:

```
df['Time'] = df.Time.dt.ceil(freq='s')  

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   Record_ID                Time
0      94704 2014-03-10 07:19:19
1      94705 2014-03-10 07:21:44
2      94706 2014-03-10 07:21:45
3      94707 2014-03-10 07:21:54
4      94708 2014-03-10 07:21:55
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. Depending on the situation, `round` and `floor` are also available.

Answer (score 19):

If you really must remove the `microsecond` part of the datetime, you can use the `Timestamp.replace` method along with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method to apply it across the series , to replace the `microsecond` part with `0`. Example -

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))
```

Demo -

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   Record_ID                       Time
0      94704 2014-03-10 07:19:19.647342
1      94705 2014-03-10 07:21:44.479363
2      94706 2014-03-10 07:21:45.479581
3      94707 2014-03-10 07:21:54.481588
4      94708 2014-03-10 07:21:55.481804

In [26]: type(df['Time'][0])
Out[26]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [27]: df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   Record_ID                Time
0      94704 2014-03-10 07:19:19
1      94705 2014-03-10 07:21:44
2      94706 2014-03-10 07:21:45
3      94707 2014-03-10 07:21:54
4      94708 2014-03-10 07:21:55
```