# What determines Pandas minimum and maximum timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The minimum `Timestamp` in Pandas is:

```py
pd.Timestamp.min
Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
```

and the maximum is:

```py
pd.Timestamp.max
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

This means you can't convert a value outside this range to a Pandas datetime:

```py
pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2500, 1, 1))
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2500-01-01 00:00:00
```

What determines these limits?

Answer (score 5):

The datetime type is stored in nanoseconds using a signed 64 bit integer.
The range, then, is [2^-63;2^63 -1 ]. Using the 0 as the unix epoch (1970/01/01 00:00:00.0), you can see by running this code that the result is approximately 292 years from the 0 (unix epoch). The maximum, then, is the date represented with a leading `0` followed by 63 `1`

Run this code to prove it yourself.

```
max_int=2**63-1 # maximum integer
max_int/=10**9 # from nanoseconds to seconds
max_int/=86400 # from seconds to days
max_int/=365 # from days to years (suppose no leap years)
print(1970+max_int) # print the maximum year, with an error of days
```

EDIT: as written in the comment below by Ben, I didn't report the source. [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)

Comment: [confirmed in the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations).

Comment: Thank you, so the answer is because Pandas uses nanosecond precision? If I change the 10**9, then I could figure out what the limits would be if Pandas used a different precision?

Comment: Exactly. BTW now I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827472/6110285) that allows to do that. So the limits would be in the order of a billion years.

Answer (score 0):

The source is the amount of nanoseconds derived from the largest and smallest amount of integers storable in numpy's `int64` class, with some tweaks. You can see the implementation and a helpful comment [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L1422).