# is there a way to generate dates for 10000 years ? starting from 1-1-1 to 9999-12-31

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numbers, data-science

I have used pandas function to create dates with this period of time, but it returned empty list.

```py
date_df = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1', end='31/12/1999')
```

Comment: `1/1/1` is interpreted as Jan 1 2001. My naïve attempt at using a 4-digit year produces an `OutOfBoundDatetime` error, as the year 1 appears to be too far in the past to represent using a 64-bit nanosecond timestamp. Someone who knows Pandas far better than me will probably have a solution.

Comment: It should be possible, but neither would it make sense nor would it be accurate (as different calendars were (are) used, and dates have been adjusted over the years - mainly to accommodate the difference from what humans consider to be an year, and what a year (complete Earth revolution around the Sun) really takes).

Comment: you could use numpy `np.arange('0001-01-01', '9999-12-31', dtype='datetime64[D]')`, but as CristiFati already pointed out, no all days make sense in this range

Answer (score 4):

Timestamps in Pandas have a min and a max:

```
pd.Timestamp.min
# Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')

pd.Timestamp.max
# Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

See further: [What determines Pandas minimum and maximum timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323548/what-determines-pandas-minimum-and-maximum-timestamp). What you could do, is use [pd.period_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) instead. So:

```
period_index = pd.period_range(start='0001-01-01', end='9999-12-31')
print(period_index)

PeriodIndex(['0001-01-01', '0001-01-02', '0001-01-03', '0001-01-04',
             '0001-01-05', '0001-01-06', '0001-01-07', '0001-01-08',
             '0001-01-09', '0001-01-10',
             ...
             '9999-12-22', '9999-12-23', '9999-12-24', '9999-12-25',
             '9999-12-26', '9999-12-27', '9999-12-28', '9999-12-29',
             '9999-12-30', '9999-12-31'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=3652059)
```