# convert javascript Date.now to pandas to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert timestamp data that has been fetched with javascript `Date.now()`  and get the `date` and `time` into `pandas.DataFrame`.
I am using `pandas.to_datetime` to convert the timestamp.

However [According to the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) `The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.`

so, converting the timestamp `1636460191573` using `pd.to_datetime('1636460191573')` give `Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:27:16.460191573')`

How do I get the date and time from the timestamp in `dd/mm/yyyy` and `hh:mm:sec` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter unit:

```
timestamp = pd.to_datetime('1636789077923', unit='ms').ceil(freq='s')

print(timestamp.date())
print(timestamp.time())

2021-11-13
07:30:03
```

Comment: `pd.__version__ == '2.0.2'`: `FutureWarning: The behavior of 'to_datetime' with 'unit' when parsing strings is deprecated. In a future version, strings will be parsed as datetime strings, matching the behavior without a 'unit'. To retain the old behavior, explicitly cast ints or floats to numeric type before calling to_datetime.`

Answer (score 0):

reduce precission as to remove the ms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57980631/2481350). Extract the date and time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57980631/2481350)

```
timestamp = pd.to_datetime('1636789077923', unit='ms').ceil(freq='s')

print(timestamp.date())
print(timestamp.time())

2021-11-13
07:30:03
```