# how to remove milliseconds or decimals in a specific dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns containing date and time(hr,min,seconds:milliseconds)
How do I remove the milliseconds from only one of the column?

```
Name   MinTime                       MaxTime
John   2020-02-20 12:00:00.12345     2020-02-20 12:00:00.12345

Desired Output
Name   MinTime                       MaxTime
John   2020-02-20 12:00:00     2020-02-20 12:00:00.12345
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: reduce precision pandas timestamp dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827169/python-reduce-precision-pandas-timestamp-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.MinTime = df.MinTime.replace(microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I convert the timestamp into datetime format

```
df['MinTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['MinTime'])
df['MinTime'] = df['MinTime'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```